# Finding the tangent plane of a point of a curve when using implicit differentiation

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

I need to find the tangent plane of this surface:

$$(z-1)^3=\sin(y^2)e^{xz}$$

at the point $(0, \sqrt \pi ,1)$

I find $dz \over dx$ and $dz \over dy$

$${dz \over dx}={-e^{xz}\sin(y^2)z \over xe^{xz}\sin(y^2)-3(z-1)^2}$$

$${dz \over dy}={-2e^{xz}y \, \cos(y^2) \over xe^{xz}\sin(y^2)-3(z-1)^2}$$

I've got the  equation for the tangent plane, but I'm not sure how to go from here?

$$z-z_0=f'_x(x_0, y_0)(x-x_0)+f'_y(x_0, y_0)(y-y_0)$$

Thanks!

Comment: There shouldn't be primes on the $f$. $f_x$, $f_y$ already means you are taking the partial derivative of $f$, which I assume you are taking it to be $z = f(x,y)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that your solution is fine. You just need to evaluate your derivatives at the given point, so $x_0 = 0, y_0 = \sqrt{\pi}, z_0 = 1$.

Here is a good [resource.](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/GradientVectorTangentPlane.aspx)

I will write you a solution (with hidden spoilers) so you can work it out and try to get it on your own. (This is a more general approach than what you have.)

First, let's think of the given surface as a level surface of a function in three variables.

Let $F: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$.  What would be a good candidate for our function $F$? (There are more than one possible answers.)

> $$F(x,y,z) = \sin(y^2)e^{xz} - (z-1)^3$$
>
>  With this $F$, your surface is the zero set $F(x,y,z) = 0$.
>
>  Also possible are $$F(x,y,z) = (z-1)^3 - \sin(y^2)e^{xz},$$
>
>  and the surface is the zero set $F(x,y,z) = 0.$
>
>  You can even do $$F(x,y,z) = \sin(y^2)e^{xz} - (z-1)^3 + 1,$$ 
>
>  and the surface is the level $F(x,y,z) = 1$.

Now, what we need to do is to find:

$F_x$, $F_y$, and $F_z$ at the point $(0,\sqrt{\pi},1)$

Then, the equation of the tangent plane according to the formula in the link is:

> $0 = F_x(0,\sqrt{\pi},1)(x-0) + F_y(0,\sqrt{\pi},1)(y-\sqrt{\pi}) + F_z(0,\sqrt{\pi},1)(z-1)$

It remains to evaluate the partial derivatives at the given point.

Seeing that you don't really have problems taking derivatives, I'll leave that task to you.

Let me know if you need further clarification.

Comment: Thanks! That was very helpful! I didn't think about putting all that = 0